# animation in characters in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Let's understand the my requirement / question.

- I have to develop following things in my application.
- Application starts with a view controller ( obviously )
- Now, after loading the view controller
- "Touch me" characters should enter on screen animating, animation direction should be random.

OK. Let me clarify again.

The aim of question is animation & Touch.

- **T** (part of touch me) should enter from any corner of the screen & then **o** & ten **u** ...

After all character adjusts on the center screen, touch - tap event must be handled.

How to do this?

Comment: This encompassed a number of questions that are best answered by reading the documentation and going through the sample projects at http://developer.apple.com/iphone and http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/navigation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Watch out. I have implemented following in view did load.

```
lblTT.hidden=YES; lbloo.hidden=YES; lbluu.hidden=YES; lblcc.hidden=YES; lblhh.hidden=YES;
lblT.hidden=YES; lblo.hidden=YES; lblu.hidden=YES; lblc.hidden=YES; lblh.hidden=YES;
animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
[animation setDelegate:self];
animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(lblTT.frame.origin.x+17,lblTT.frame.origin.y+29)];
animation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(lblT.frame.origin.x,lblT.frame.origin.y)];
animation.autoreverses = NO;
animation.removedOnCompletion=YES;
animation.repeatCount = 0;
animation.duration = 1;
animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
lblT.hidden=NO;
[lblT.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"T"];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(hideT) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```